# Can a Netty pipeline still do work after the close future is done?

Tags: netty

In our Netty client, there are instances where we call:

```
channel.closeFuture().sync();
```

and after it completes, we see more data coming into one of our handlers.  We've written an Http2ConnectionHandler and that's the handler receiving data even after this close future completes.

My question is: when does the close future complete and can more work be done by the pipeline after it does?

ANSWER:
Yes, close future fires and THEN the pipeline is torn down as Norman says below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More specific once a Channel is closed the ChannelPipeline should be teared down, which means all handlers will be removed and `handlerRemoved` for each `ChannelHandler` will be called.

Comment: Ah ok, then in that case we may have uncovered a bug.  I'll try to reproduce it.  We're seeing activity in a handler after the channel closed future fires.

Comment: well the future is completed before channelInactive is called as the futures are always notified first. So I think what you see is expected. That said it should not be called after channelInactive was called

Answer (score 0):

The `closeFuture()` is fired when the underlying channel (in HTTP/2 case, the TCP/IP connection) is closed. This can happen because either you or the remote peer closed the connection. The Netty pipeline associated with a closed channel should not receive any more data. Explicitly reading/writing to a closed channel will throw an exception.